# Custom Calendar that follows a pattern

Tags: mysql, calendar

I need to create a custom calendar that contains a period and sales/non-sales period as well:

- Period has the pattern as 4 Weeks, 4 Weeks, 5 Weeks, 4 Weeks, 4 Weeks, 5 Weeks and repeats over and over.
- Sales has a pattern of 9 Weeks Sale and 4 Weeks Non-Sale and this repeats over and over as well.

I don't know how to achieve this though, building this calendar for 5 years would be really annoying if I would need to do create it on Excel (plus I hate Excel). Please help!!!

I have managed to get the Week Number etc... right by using a Cartesian Join and also get the Week Number right. So far what I have managed to do you can find below:

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT *,

DAYNAME(gen_date) as day_of_week,

YEAR(gen_date) as calendar_year,

'2019/2020' as calendar_period,

FLOOR(1 + ((number) -1) / 7) as Week_number,

FLOOR(1 + ((number) -1) / 91) as Quarter,

gen_date - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(gen_date)) DAY AS week_commencing_start,

gen_date - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(gen_date)-6) DAY AS week_commencing_end

FROM


(select * from 
(select (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) number, adddate('2019-04-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) gen_date



from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where gen_date between '2019-04-01' and '2020-03-29') b;
```

If anyone wants to check the pattern please have a look at this Excel file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yWUWEkCoCXau5kST18rI2YOWMW4sxQUC/view?usp=sharing

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this will give you what you want.

```
set @startdate = '2019-04-01';
set @weekoffset = WEEK(@startDate) -1 ;

WITH RECURSIVE weeks(wk, wkn, auxperiod, period, sales) AS 
(
  select @startDate , WEEK(@startDate) + CASE WHEN WEEK(@startDate) - @weekoffset > 0 THEN -@weekoffset ELSE 52 - @weekoffset end, 1, 1, 'S'
  UNION ALL 
  select DATE_ADD(wk, INTERVAL 1 WEEK), 
        WEEK(DATE_ADD(wk, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) + CASE WHEN WEEK(DATE_ADD(wk, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) - @weekoffset > 0 THEN -@weekoffset ELSE 52 - @weekoffset end, 
       case when auxperiod + 1 > 13 then 1 else auxperiod + 1 end, 
       case when auxperiod + 1 = 5 or auxperiod + 1 = 9 or auxperiod + 1 = 14 then period + 1 else period end, 
       case when auxperiod + 1 < 10 or auxperiod + 1 > 13 then 'S' else 'N' end
    FROM weeks 
    WHERE wk < DATE_ADD(@startdate, INTERVAL 5 Year) -- end date - add 5 years to startdate
)
select * FROM weeks
```

The generated table will have columns:

- wk (the week starting date),
- wkn (number of the week according to the start date)
- auxperiod (auxiliar column used just for calculations)
- period (the period number)
- sales (value 'S' for Sales week and 'N' for non sales week)

Comment: That worked pretty well! Just had to change a bit to add quarter!

Thanks Eduardo! Obrigado!